# How To Join Different tables and sort according to most occuring record

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

[image]

I would like to make a query which counts all users who registered since 1995 by city_name and then sort by the project with the most registration. 
This is what I have tried so far (pls note I am still a bit new to sql):

```
SELECT COUNT (userID), users.userID 
FROM users FULL JOIN p.projectID FROM project 
WHERE registration_date >= '01/01/1995' 
GROUP BY (SELECT * FROM project WHERE project.projectID = user.projectID)
```

However, this is not returning the right result. Thanks for help

Comment: It's probably returning an error because your syntax has at least two mistakes.  However, if you want to sort your data, you need an order by clause.

Comment: can I just replace the "group by" with "order by"? and also, how can I count them by the city name? at the moment, I'm not including the city table at all

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
SELECT 
  Project.ProjectID,
  City.CityID,
  COUNT(UserID) AS UserCount
FROM Project
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN City ON City.CityID = Users.CityID
WHERE
  Users.registration_date > '1/1/1995'
GROUP BY Project.ProjectID, City.CityID
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(UserID) DESC
```

You said 'sort by the project with the most registration'; this actually sorts by the Project+City that has the most registrations.

You can sub-select for the total registrations for a project, and include that in your ORDER BY, but that strikes me as a bit of an odd output, so I made an assumption :-)